# image dpi and conversion

Tags: images, dpi

I want to scan some images for text size `B5`.  What would be a good dpi to use?  How can one change to a different dpi value on `png` files?

Comment: Is there a program that can changes the image size by using a smaller dpi?

Comment: The images have already been scanned.

Answer (score 0):

You do not change dpi in `png`. The DPI is an option for the scanner.

Once the image is scanned - the dpi is stored in the image file for the printing. So that when you send image to the printer, it can do a proper pixel-per-inch conversion.

Which DPI to use - is completely up you, the rule of thumb: scan, look at the image, do you see all tiny parts? If no - increase DPI. Image file is huge? Decrease DPI.

There is no standard for which DPI to use, but usually it is in the range of 100-600. And it does not matter what is the size of paper on the scanner's bed.

Comment: Is there any program to decrease the dpi if the file size is too large?

Comment: @konmi Any graph editor. `GIMP` for example.

Comment: Because I got many files, changes with gimp is impractical.  Or can one use it on the command line ?

Comment: If the task is to reduce file sizes - you can use `ImageMagick`. Read here, for example: https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php